# How to pipe the output forked/cluster processes into the master stdout/stderr

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, stdout, stderr

When doing `worker = cluster.fork()` I would like to be able to forward the stdout and stderr streams into the master Node.js process.

How can I do that?

I tried doing:

```
worker = cluster.fork();
worker.process.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
//             ^ this is null
```

A workaround would be to use messages, but I want to be able to stream content.

```
worker.on("message", function(msg){
  console.log("Master says:" + msg);
});
...
worker.send({message:'hello'});
```

---

How can I access the stdout of the forked process/cluster?

Answer (score 0):

please see the code below

for the master process:

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
cluster.settings.stdio=[0, 1, 2, 'ipc'];
cluster.settings.silent = true; //Whether or not to send output to parent's stdio. Default: false. 
cluster.settings.exec = './hello' //the forked process's file path
const childW = cluster.fork();
const child = childW.process;
```

for the forked process: `./hello.js`

```
console.log('hello')
```